# How to run bin/cake.php locally using database from Vagrant machine?

Tags: cakephp, vagrant

I have my CakePHP application on my local machine that is rsynced to a vagrant box I've created. My Vagrant configuration is below:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

$set_environment_variables = <<SCRIPT
tee "/etc/profile.d/vars.sh" > "/dev/null" <<EOF
# Domain Name (excluding protocol)
export DOMAIN="cake.local"

# Unprivileged User
export UNPRIV_USER="web"
export UNPRIV_USER_PUB_KEY="removed"

# MySQL
export MYSQL_USER="wizard"
export MYSQL_PASSWORD="developer"
export MYSQL_HOST="localhost"
export MYSQL_DATABASE="cake_cms"
export MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="developer"
EOF
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-20.04"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.15"
  config.vm.synced_folder "app/", "/var/www/html", type: "rsync", owner: "web", group: "www-data", rsync__auto: true, rsync__exclude: ['app/vendor/*']
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $set_environment_variables, run: "always"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "512"
  end
end
```

When I attempt to run `php bin/cake.php bake model Users` from my local machine I get the following error:

```
2021-04-13 21:51:15 Error: [Cake\Database\Exception\MissingExtensionException] Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql cannot be used due to a missing PHP extension or unmet dependency in C:\Users\JR2\Projects\cake-php-boilerplate\app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Connection.php on line 202
```

This is because it's trying to connect to the MySQL database locally, which doesn't exist.

How am I able to have my local `bin/cake.php` connect to the database on the vagrant box?

Comment: Most likely the easiest thing will be to just run the command in the vagrant box.  `ssh -t` would be one way to run that within your local environment.

Comment: I have tried this, but the rsync seems to be 1 way. The changes are not reflected locally when the model is generated on the vagrant machine.

Comment: Do you require rsync for some specific reason? Might be easier to just enable or force a method that does 2-way syncing - like `type: "virtualbox"`

Comment: 2 way syncing in my previous experiences has ended badly. I've had instances where I've done work on the virtual machine and I've lost work locally. I'm constantly modifying the development environment during development, and re-running provision scripts to make sure things work ok. I'm worried about data loss with 2 way syncing.